# The loop to count words in a list not working

Tags: python

This is my code to count the number of times a word occurs in a string. The first loop runs fine, but when I use a second loop to print the result, the output is very different.

```
count = 0
sentence = input("enter sentence  ")
words = list(sentence.split())
dict = {}

for i in words:
    dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1

print(dict)

# loop below must give same output as loop 1 but its not

length = len(words) 
for j in range(length):
    # print(words[j])
    dict[j] = dict.get(words[j], 0)

print(dict)
```

After running code

```
Enter sentence  
hi hi
```

Output of first loop

```
{'Hello': 1, 'hi': 2}
```

Output of second loop

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}   
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is the second loop not giving same output?

Comment: I get `{0: 1, 1: 2, 'hello': 1, 2: 2, 'hi': 2}` from your second loop

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: As an aside, do not name a dict `dict` or it will be confusing when the built-in dict function no longer works.

Comment: You are doing two different things: first loop is word by word and that word is used as a key in your dict. Second loop is looping over the index of each word and adding that index to your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be one of the better examples of why the names of variables matter.

Your first loop:

```
for i in words:
    dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
```

Uses `i` as a variable name -- implying an index. It is not an index; you are looping word by word over `words` and `i` is a string. (each of the words `['hello', 'hi', 'hi']` in this example one by one.)

Your second loop:

```
length = len(words) 
for j in range(length):
    # print(words[j])
    dict[j] = dict.get(words[j], 0)
```

IS an index into that list of words. However, you are now adding those indices to your dict as new keys. (`0` and `1` respectively.) The old keys of `'hello'` and `'hi`' remain.

You program is better as:

```
sentence = "hello hi hi"
words = sentence.split()
di = {}       # don't use dict as a variable name! It destroys the function
              # by that same name
# looping over words like this produces each word in turn
for word in words:                 
    di[word] = di.get(word, 0) + 1

print(di)

# loop below must give same output as loop 1 but its not
#       now it is...

length = len(words) 
# j is a numeric index in this case
for index in range(length):   
    print(words[index], index)
    # need to dereference that index with words[j] to get the word
    di[words[index]] = di.get(words[index], 0)  

print(di)
```

Which then produces the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Because in first cycle i is of type str and contains words of sentence. So dict has words as keys.
And in second cycle j is of type int (from range) so for example on first iteration you get

```
dict(0) = dict.get('hi', 0) = 0, not 'hi'
```

In other words you never add words as keys in second cycle.